# Django - have created a pdf file using ReportLab but how do i store it into a FileField record?

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab, filefield

In views.py:

```
        c = canvas.Canvas(str(num)+'.pdf')
        c.setPageSize((page_width, page_height))
        c.drawInlineImage('logo.jpg', margin, page_height - image_height - margin,
                          image_width, image_height)
        c.setFont('Arial', 80)
        text = 'INVOICE'
        c.save()
        tt2 = Invoices_list.objects.all().filter(Number=num)
        tt2.update(document=c)
```

In models.py:

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='temp/', blank=True, null=True)
```

My view creates a record and completes the Date & Name record, i then create the pdf which works fine (can see it in my root directory) but how do i send it straight to the FileField as the tt2.update(document=c) produces a filename of "<reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas object at 0x000001D51FB442E0> and not 333.pdf (where num=333) although 333.pdf is in the root of my django project. How do i copy it from my root into the FileField record, and next issue is i host using Heroku so not sure if this will cause additional problems.
Thanks in advance

Any

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import your Model and then create a new object within your view to populate your database (if this is what you mean with `send it to the FileField`) like so:

**Views.py**

```
from your_app.models import Invoices

c = canvas.Canvas(str(num)+'.pdf')
        c.setPageSize((page_width, page_height))
        c.drawInlineImage('logo.jpg', margin, page_height - image_height - margin,
                          image_width, image_height)
        c.setFont('Arial', 80)
        text = 'INVOICE'
        c.save()

obj, created = Invoices.objects.update_or_create(
                                defaults={
                                    'document': c,                                    
                                }
)
```

**Update:**

Please include a doc check in your Model like so:

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to='temp/',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        content_types = ['application/pdf'])
```

Comment: Tried the above but got error: 'Canvas' object has no attribute '_committed'. I've imported my model already with "tt2 = Invoices_list.objects.all().filter(Number=num)" and tried "tt2.document = c" and "tt2.save()" but also get error

Comment: i've also done similar as you suggested "tt2.update(document=c)" and it passes with no errors but when i look at my file the filename is  "reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas object at 0x000001CDF2F87CA0" (instead of  "333.pdf" where num=333) and doesn't open my file. Appreciate your help

Comment: Edited my post. Also could you share print(c) after you created the pdf.

Comment: print(c) displays <reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas object at 0x000001CDF2F87CA0>